# HTML input type number format large number. Introducing space or other separator

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, w3c

I am presenting the user on one device with a large number, like this:

```
123 879 233 223 211 782 782
```

The numbers are presented in **chunks of three**, as can be seen.

Now the user is supposed to enter these numbers on another device.

I would like to present them the same way as he/she are typing them.

So I **CURRENTLY** have a

```
  input type=number pattern='\d*'
```

I would like it to basically be (pseudo) :

```
 type=text keyboard=numbers pattern='[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3} ...'
```

The type number is **useful on mobile devices** because it brings up the **numbers keypad** only which in this case is more relevant and user friendly.

**1)** Is there a way to get the numbers keyboard for a **standard input type=text**?

**2)** If not, is there a way to format the numbers entered into the numbers input field?

**3)** If not, can we fire all people involved with W3C due to incompetence? Rather than keeping the input type=text they could have introduced pattern allowed on that, and allowed for an attribute that says, keyboard=numbers.

Comment: how is the wanted input? `123 879 ...` or `123879...`?

Comment: Does input type=text pattern='\d*' not bring up the numbers keypad?

Comment: @Jonah No it doesn't.

Comment: @Nina, the first case.

Comment: I answered the question myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go,

I have two input fields. One with type number, that is positioned:absolute and **hidden using opacity.**

When you focus the input to type, the hidden number input is focused instead.

The inputs there is picked up and placed into the visually **available input type text.**

```
<input type=text name=guid placeholder='18 digits' modulo='3' max='18' />


function numberInput(input) {
        var modulo   = parseInt(input.attr('modulo'));
        var max      = parseInt(input.attr('max')) || Infinity;

        var keyboard = $('<input type=number pattern="\d*" style="opacity:0; position:absolute;">');

        keyboard.insertBefore(input);

        input.on('focus', function() {
                keyboard.focus();
        });

        keyboard.on('input', function fn(){
                var tmp = keyboard.val(), val = '';

                if ( tmp.length > max ) {
                        keyboard.val( tmp = tmp.substring(0, max) )
                }

                var i = -1;
                while ( ++i < tmp.length ) {
                        if ( i > 0 && i % 3 === 0 ) {
                                val += ' ';
                        }
                        val += tmp.charAt(i);
                }

                input.val(val);

                // Trigger original event for external listeners 
                input.trigger.apply(input, arguments);
                // Note, the event target passed to trigger is now on the wrong object. To get the right object, simply change it to: 
                // input.trigger.call(input, 'input', arguments);
                // Note that for the latter, attempts to modify the value won't get picked up. 

        });
}
```